# Source Overrides MIME type issues .mjs

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I set up a simple test website, using Chrome Dev Overrides. For static html it works fine. For javascript files it works fine. However, when I change the .js to .mjs (to convert my test script to modules) - it ***fails*** with the attached error.

I gather that Chrome Dev Overrides reports all (static) files as text/html which is generally not an issue, except Chrome is enforcing the Spec in this instance (for .mjs) to report the correct MIME type.

I'm not an expert on this. How to solve this?

[image: error when .mjs files are loaded through Chrome Dev Source Overrides]